# Different results for `hclust' and `agnes' using average link

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hclust

I am applying a simple clustering procedure to a custom simulated similarity matrix. (https://github.com/ewouddt/Files/blob/master/sim_col.RData)

However I am noticing a difference between the `hclust` and `agnes` procedure when using an *average link* (Note: I observed the same behaviour for a *complete link* as well)

```
load("sim_col.RData") # A 606 x 606 similarity matrix
library(cluster)

c1 <- hclust(as.dist(1-sim_col),method="average")
c2 <- as.hclust(agnes(as.dist(1-sim_col),diss=TRUE,method="average"))

dev.new()
plot(c1)
dev.new()
plot(c2)

cut1 <- cutree(c1,k=20)
cut2 <- cutree(c2,k=20)
cut1
cut2

sort(table(cut1))
cut1
# cut1
# 10  18   9  19   3  20   4  11   7  15  17   5   6  12  16   2   8   1  13  14 
#  2   5   7   8  11  13  14  14  15  19  19  21  23  26  27  31  33  80  95 143
sort(table(cut2))
# cut2
# 18  20  19  11  17   7   8   4  12   5   9   3  10  16   2   6  14  13   1  15 
#  4   6   8   9   9  13  13  14  15  16  17  19  20  29  31  31  54  62 115 121
```

As expected the dendrograms look different due the different order of `hclust` and `agnes`. 
However cutting the labels (at `k=20` for example) shows different (although similar) results for the observations. (For example you can see that the quantities of the labels differs between the 2 results)

Am I making a stupid mistake or are `hclust` and `agnes` not supposed to return the exact same result after cutting the tree?
If the 2 procedures are not supposed to return the same result, wherein lies the difference of the 2 functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for single-link, the clustering result may not be uniquely determined.

Consider the following data set:

```
1 2 3 4
```

The are three minima: merging 1 and 2, or 2 and 3, or 3 and 4.

Except for single-link, we will get different results depending on whether we first merge 2 and 3 or one of the other pairs.

In particular, the usual algorithms will *not* be able to guarantee to find the optimal solution. If you would want to guarantee that, you will likely be NP-complete. But it may also not matter much.