# Do agnes() and hclust() do the exact same thing?

Tags: r, data-science, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I'm using the clValid package (Brock et., 2008) to evaluate the stability of a cluster solution.

Interestingly, the package its you select Hierarchical Clustering and AGNES as if these were different algorithms.

It outputs a ranked list with the overall best combinations of distance metric, linkage method and clustering algorithm and here, **hierarchical clustering and AGNES seem to achieve different results when using the same distance metric and the same linkage method**.

So to gain some definite clarity: Do agnes() and hclust() indeed do the exact same thing? Is the clValid package just misleading in how the ranks are displayed or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://www.davidzeleny.net/anadat-r/doku.php/en:hier-agglom_r) is some relevant information detailing the differences in the use of the Ward method between the two functions.

It explains that hclust() uses two varieties of the Ward method - 'ward.D' and 'ward.D2'. 'ward.D2' is the genuine Ward method - while 'ward.D' is something else. Typing in just 'ward' in hclust() results in the use of 'ward.D'. In agnes() there is only one type of 'ward' option - which is the genuine Ward method.

For differences in other types of linkages read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729911/different-results-for-hclust-and-agnes-using-average-link#new-answer?newreg=d4faf69051324e4fb088d7846ada57e7)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow deurali! Please consider adding some relevant parts in the answer from the link you have pasted. So that, even if there is a change in the future in those websites, users would be able to understand the solution.